# Serial Port listening in C#

Tags: c#, ocr

There are loads of questions about listening of devices on Serial Port using C#.

However I couldn't find something that will be useful for my application and working.

Now this is a code i finally decided to use however I cannot see why it will not output anything:

```
namespace SerialPorts
```

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort();

```
     myPort.DataReceived += MyPortDataReceived;
     myPort.PortName = "COM3";
     myPort.BaudRate = 19200;
     myPort.DataBits = 7;
     myPort.Parity = Parity.Even;
     myPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;

     myPort.Open();

     Console.ReadLine();

     myPort.Close();

  }

  static void MyPortDataReceived(object sender,
     SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
  {
     var myPort = sender as SerialPort;
     Console.WriteLine(myPort.ReadLine());
  }
    }
```

}

My device is OCR PASSORT reader.

I expect a string when i swipe a passport. However I get nothing, no output at all.

Can you please help me what can i do to make it output a string at least?

BTW I know the OCR reader is working since there is an app coming with it that outputs its data and when I use apps that test the COM i get data but with this code I get nothing. Any help will be appreciated!

Regards!

Comment: 7 bit even parity is archaic.  Most device these days use 8 bit no parity.

Comment: It is not archaic.  You cannot ignore the Handshake property, many serial port devices pay attention to it and won't send anything when they think your machine is not powered up or not ready to receive data.   When you don't set it, you must set the RTSEnable and DTREnable properties to *true* yourself.